# Using a keyword between list names to apply a function between elements

Tags: r, list

I have a list `l1` that have file names for each of the list elements. I also have a second list `l2`, that have some of the same components in the names of the list elements as `l1` (i.e., "2013").

I would like to apply the `mean` function between the list element with the name "C:/Users/2013_mean.csv" and the three elements in `l2` based on the keyword "2013". How do I selectively choose that list element, and apply the function between that element and the three elements in `l2`?

```
# File List
l1 <- list(2,3)
names(l1) <- c("C:/Users/2013_mean.csv",
               "C:/Users/2013_median.csv")

# Other List
l2 <- list(8,9,10)
names(l2) <- c("2013_A",
               "2013_B",
               "2013_C")

# Attempt to get to the expected
# Look for intersect between the File list names and the Other List names 
set <- intersect(l1[grep("2013", names(l1))], l2)

# Apply function between the list
Map(
  function(i, j) {
    mean(i, j)
  },
  i = a[set],
  j = b[set]
)
```

This is what I expect to get as the output:

```
expected <- list(mean(c(l1[[l1]], l2[[1]])),
                 mean(c(l1[[11]], l2[[2]])),
                 mean(c(l1[[l11]], l2[[3]]))
                 )
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: what did you get from `set <- intersect(` as against the expected?

Comment: It returns a empty list object. The `intersect()` and `Map` function were my attempts at obtaining the expected, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we need

```
lapply(l2, function(x) mean(c(x, l1[[grep("2013_mean", names(l1))]])))
$`2013_A`
[1] 5

$`2013_B`
[1] 5.5

$`2013_C`
[1] 6
```

Comment: If your R version is 4.1.0 or lower, the above `(l2, \(x)` would be `(l2, function(x)`, reminder to myself it's time to leave 'Camp Pontanezen'.

Comment: @Chris sorry, I forgot about this version difference.  Just to work for all versions, changed it to `function(x)`. thanks

Comment: I find staying up to date with version releases and the some thousands of packages you must have admirable.